# How to clone a TFVC repository of VisualStudio.com using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-code, tfvc

I installed Visual Studio Code and the extension of "Visual Studio Team Services". I pressed F1 and "team: login" and got the following error message.

> (team) You must open a repository folder in order to use the Team Services extension.

How to create a repository folder using VSC? There are a lot of information about Git on VisualStudio.com(Visual Studio team services) but not TFVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to use Visual Studio Code to connect a TFVC project by using [Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) for Visual Studio Code.

Make sure you are using version *1.116.0* or later, it provides support for the TFVC source control system!

> **Create your TFVC workspace**
>
> With TFVC, the extension uses information about the current workspace
>   to determine how to connect to Team Services (or your Team Foundation
>   Server). **Workspaces can be created using the Visual Studio IDE,
>   Eclipse or with the JetBrains IDEs (e.g, Android Studio, IntelliJ).**
>
> ***Note:*** At this time, you will need to have a ***local*** TFVC workspace already available on your local machine.

To learn more about the TFVC support, review this tutorial [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md) or watch the [overview video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be).

Besides, you need working on *Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2* (and later).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of VSC, and I'm using TFS on VisualStudio.com. So right now I had to install one of these software ( Visual Studio IDE, Eclipse or with the JetBrains IDEs (e.g, Android Studio, IntelliJ)) to initialize a local TFVC workspace. And then I can use VSC to work on it.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Yes, that's right. More details you could watch the overview video.

Comment: I'm a little bit disappointed that I need these heavy ides to clone it.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Sorry for that, The mainstream of tool for TFVC is still visual studio. The support for  Visual Studio Code also recently  announced. Which can improve so much more future.

Answer (score 0):

TFVC repos are not the same as Git repos. Each Team Project can only have a single one. If you have an existing Team Project without a TFVC repo, you can create it via the web interface. If it already has a TFVC repository, you can't create a second one.

Comment: Actually, I just need to work on a project in a TFS repository on a brand new laptop and I cannot find a way to connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

Update from [PatrickLu-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5391065/patricklu-msft)'s solution:

If you have apple silicon (M1 / M2 chip), Microsoft's solution will likely not work for you. Check out [this fork of that repo from JetBrains](https://github.com/JetBrains/team-explorer-everywhere/releases):

The same set of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019) will work for this release.